# Basic question about the inequality involving supremum

Tags: inequality, supremum-and-infimum

stackexchange people.

I'd like to check whether my basic inequality is vaild or not.

Which is below:

If $\sup |{A}|, \sup |{B}|$ are different,

then $| \sup |{A}|- \sup |{B}||
=\sup |{A}|- \sup |{B}|$
(we can assume this because of the assumption)

$\le \sup (|{A}|-|{B}|)$

(Since $ \sup(A+B) \le \sup {A}+ \sup {B}$)

$\le \sup |A-B|$. (Because the right inside term is bigger or equal to the left term.)

Is this inequality right?

Comment: What are $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @Gribouillis I guess those are any real number.

Comment: If $A$ is a real number, what is $\sup |A|$ ?

Comment: @Gribouillis Are there conditions where those inequality not hold? Actually I try to use this inequality to prove some statement. Which is my latest question on stackexchange about approximation. More specifically I was supposed to use above inequality to show that $\Delta$ is continuous on a given closed interval. Please check my another question.

Comment: @Gribouillis sorry for not able to link to question.

Comment: The inequality cannot hold if it does not have a precise meaning. If $A$ is a real number, I don't know what $\sup |A|$ means, the inequality is meaningless. Where does it come from?

Comment: @Gribouillis You're right. It's a false question. $sup|A|$ is $sup|f(x)-\lambda*P_n(x)|$ on a given closed interval. where $P_n(x)$ is a fixed polynomial and $f(x)$ is bounded function on the same closed interval. $|B|$ is almost same but change $\lambda$ to some fixed real number on real line. and $\lambda$ is real number. and it can vary.

Answer (score 1):

If $f$ and $g$ are real functions defined on a set $E$, let us write $\sup_E f = \sup \{f(x)\  |\ x\in E\}$. Then for any $x\in E$ one has
$$f(x) + g(x)\le \sup_E f + \sup_E g$$
hence
$$\sup_E(f+g)\le \sup_E f + \sup_E g$$

If $A$ and $B$ are bounded functions defined on $E$, one has
$$\sup_E |A| \le \sup_E (|A| - |B |+ |B|)\le \sup_E(|A|-|B|) + \sup_E |B|$$
hence
$$\sup_E |A| - \sup_E |B|\le \sup_E (|A|-|B|)$$
One also has
$$\forall x\in E, |A(x)|-|B(x)|\le |A(x)-B(x)|\Longrightarrow \sup_E(|A|-|B|)\le \sup_E |A-B|$$

Comment: thx a lot indeed! have a good day!